# Interface for services good practice

Tags: c#, interface

I have two services and one common interface they implement:

```
interface IService{string Solve(IObject obj)}
```

But this two services get different params:

```
class First: IObject{
  string str {get; set;}
  int numb {get; set;}
}
class Second: IObject{
  string str {get; set;}
  int numb {get; set;}
  int numb2 {get; set;}
}
```

And I don't know how to define `IObject` to get access to `str` and `numb` in the first service and `str`, `numb` and `numb2` in the second service.

Comment: "I need type to have two properties and three properties at the same time" (which is essentially what currently questions asks for) makes no sense. You definitely need to [edit] question to clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could make `IService` generic `IService<T>` with `Solve(T obj)` and a constraint of `where T : IObject` then the service would be `FirstService : IService<First>` and you'd have `Solve(First obj)` and you'd have access to all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use service this way as you seeking best practices. And use dependency injection to access the services from controllers.

1. Define Service, Domain classes and interfaces.

```
public class Service : Attribute { }

//Domain Classes
public class First{
  string str {get; set;}
  int numb {get; set;}
}

public class Second{
  string str {get; set;}
  int numb {get; set;}
  int numb2 {get; set;}
}

//Services
[Service]
public class DoService1Stuff()
{
     private readonly FirstManager _firstManager;
     public DoService1Stuff(FirstManager firstManager)
     {
         _firstManager= firstManager;
     }
     
     //Implement your task
     public Do(First first)
     {
         _firstManager.method1(first);
     }
}
[Service]
public class DoService2Stuff()
{
     private readonly SecondManager _secondManager;
     public DoService1Stuff(SecondManager secondManager)
     {
         _secondManager= secondManager;
     }
     
     //Implement your task
     public Do(Second second)
     {
       _secondManager.method1(second);
     }
}

interface IFirst
{
  string method1(First first);
  int method2();
}

interface ISecond
{
    string method1(Second second);
    int method2();
    int method3();
}
```

2. Implement Interfaces using manager classes

```
public class FirstManager : IFirst
{
    string method1(First first)
    {
       //access db or business stuff
    }
    int method2(){}
}

public class SecondManager : ISecond
{
    string method1(Second second)
     { //
     }
    int method2(){}
    int method3(){}
}
```

3. Register services through dependency injection in startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IFirst, FirstManager>();
services.AddTransient<ISecond, SecondManager>();
```

4. Access services in controllers

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff1([FromServicec] DoService1Stuff doService1Stuff)
{
    var first = new First
    {
        str="hello",
        numb=2020;
    };

    return Ok(doService1Stuff.Do(first))
}
//You can do same for second service.
```

Answer (score -1):

IObject is an interface, not likely to have any content.
First is the object with str and numb. Second is the object with str, numb, and numb2.
Define your object with First (or Second) as the parent object:

```
class OtherObject : First
{
    //you will have access to First's str and numb
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not likely to have any content"?